# how use getContentResolver in a class without activity?

Tags: android

my class looks like this:

```
public class sendInformation{

  public void test() throws Exception {
    Uri uri = SuspiciousActivityTable.CONTENT_URI;
    getContentResolver().update(uri, values2, where,new String[]{"Null"});
    }
  }
}
```

but it say  `getContentResolver()` doesn't exist, I know I need a Context or Activity to make this work but how do I get the correct Context here?

Comment: `public void class` That doesn't make any sense. Classes can't have a return type.

Comment: Ok so this class get called from another class which extends activity so i supposed to pass that context how i can do that?

Comment: see my edit. Usually you pass off `this` to `test()`

Comment: I'm really new in this, i call the method like this from my activity class test("how pass the context?") how i pass the context from my activity class to test();?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You will need to pass off a Context, even the [`ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) class needs a valid context to be instantiated.

Simplest way is as an argument to the method:

```
public void test(Context context) throws Exception {
    Uri uri = SuspiciousActivityTable.CONTENT_URI;
    context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values2, where,new String[]{"Null"});
  }
```

And to call: (assuming that the class that contains `test` is instantiated *and* your Activity's name is `MyActivity` <- Replace with the `Activity` name you're calling `test()` *from*)

```
try{
    sendInformationInstanceVariable.test (MyActivity.this);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`MyActivity.this` can be shortened to just `this` **if** you're not calling `test()` from inside an anonymous inner class.

Also, if your class really doesn't have a good reason to be instantiated, consider making `test()` a `static` method, like this:

```
public static void test(Context context) throws Exception {
        Uri uri = SuspiciousActivityTable.CONTENT_URI;
        context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values2, where,new String[]{"Null"});
      }
```

Then from your `Activity`, you call this method without needing an instance:

```
try{
    sendInformation.test (MyActivity.this);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Lastly, throwing `Exception` is bad practice, do don't do it without good reason and if you do have a good reason, be as specific as possible.

Comment: thanks a lot i was so confusing about this, is easy when you understand what are you doing thanks :)

Comment: how would you do it in a service? My understanding is that you _cannot_ pass context to a service.

Comment: @robertotomás A Service isa Context

Answer (score 9):

Somewhere between where your application starts (and you have access to `getApplicationContext()`) and the point where you call `test()`, you'll need to pass in a `Context` to your `sendInformation` class. I would look at what lifecycle your sendInformation class has and compare it to the various Android components (Application, Activity, Fragment) and use the appropriate context from there:

- Application: `getApplicationContext()`
- Activity: this (as Activity extends Context)
- Fragment: `getActivity()`