# How to call Content Resolver outside of a activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a button in a listview that needs to update the db on clicking. So I have to place the `OnClickListener` in the `bindView` method of the `CursorAdapter` class. So, I cannot invoke

`int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentPetUri, values, null, null);`

Since its a static context, I cannot use `Context.getContentResolver()` also.

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: i cannot refer a non static method from a static context

Comment: Pass a `Context`, such as the `Activity`, into the `ListAdapter`, such as via its constructor. Hold onto it in a field. Call `getContentResolver()` on that `Context`.

Comment: thanks...............

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how use getContentResolver in a class without activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077955/how-use-getcontentresolver-in-a-class-without-activity)